# Unable to override CSS styles for input type text in Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm coding this site up in Tailwind. Everything looks perfect, aside from `input` elements.

```
 <input type="text" className="bg-red-200 text-blue-400" placeholder="Enter some text"></input>
```

I can't override this no matter what I try. The only thing that has worked is a custom CSS rule in the `globals.css` file. Why isn't this working?

Comment: Are you working in react?

Comment: Check this out: https://play.tailwindcss.com/UIcxArMtr6 it works as it should here...

Comment: I am working in React, but this isn't working as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `Tailwind` in case of conflicts uses the `latest className` while styling

##### i.e Order of classes matters

Example:

```
<div class="bg-black h-screen bg-green-600"></div>
```

Output:
[image]

The `bg-black` is overridden by `bg-green-600`.

In your example, if you have placed your `custom class` in the `right most side`. It would `override` all the `conflicting classes` placed before to it (left side)

---

##### Extra: How to get `bg-black`  ?

###### Use `!` operator infront of `bg-black` as `!bg-black`

```
<div class="!bg-black h-screen bg-green-600"></div>
```

##### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that me defining custom styles somehow disabled using tailwind styles despite the CSS being valid. After disabling my custom styles in the tailwind config, the CSS in the OP worked.